Desktop Folders show in terminal (ls) and cmd-finder stack, but not on the actual desktop
The folders that are clearly in ~/Desktop, and used to show up on my actual desktop, don't any longer. The boot drive icon is still there. ls ~/Desktop shows my folders, and if I open one of those in the finder and cmd-click it's name, it shows that the parent is Desktop, so why aren't these folders showing up on the desktop??? This literally just started happening. I haven't changed anything. I do not use iCloud storage -- my iCloud storage is confirmed off for all options. I can still use the files on those folders if I get to them through navigating from the sidebar (because they were left there), but selecting the Desktop in the finder sidebar shows NO FILES?! WTF?! (I'm on Ventura 13.5.1 (22G90))

When you open a Finder window, you should see a list of folders under Favorites in the leftmost pane. One of those should be Desktop. If you select that, do you see the files you expect in the window?

No, but nb. ls ~/Desktop does show them, and if I open one of the folders directly in the finder and cmd-click the folder name at the top, it show the correct stack with Desktop as its direct parent. (Also, I've logged out/rebooted, obviously.)

(Clarifying my response: Your description is correct. The "no" is answering your specific question. The Desktop folder is there, and when I select it, it displays an empty list in the main window.)

Try clearing the bundle bit on the Desktop folder with this command:
SetFile -a b Desktop
Then relaunch the Finder.

Did it. Didn't do anything. However, I noticed that the icon for the Desktop in the finder lefthand shortcut dock has a tiny blue ... thing ... at the bottom that none of the other folders have. (I can't upload a screenshot into a comment but you can see it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XLlwf0gPdbGvRZoS6sUwLAzgRD1zVYpv)

The screenshot is normal. The Desktop folder has a special icon. Please post the output of ls -@Odel Desktop. Also, boot in safe mode and test. If you can't reproduce the problem in safe mode, it's caused by some third-party software.

I don't have macOS Ventura, but I wonder if the Finder Preferences have inadvertently changed to hide desktop folders/files? Not sure if you can do that in Ventura for files/folders, but in Big Sur (which is what I use), you can hide external/internal drives, iCloud, connected servers, CDs, just not files/folders unless there's a defaults command for that? Another thing to check is your desktop settings in system settings. Go to Desktop & Dock > Desktop & Stage Manager and see if there's a setting for hiding all folders/files on desktop?

Oh and one more thing, if you're connected to an external display, I believe desktop folders and files don't show on the external displays, and will only show on your main Mac's screen. Again, I'm on Big Sur, so things could have changed in Ventura!

@AVelj Thanks for these suggestions. There was, indeed, an option to show desktop items where you said it should be, but turning it on didn't do anything. (I don't think I'm using stage manager, whatever that is.) I'll look into the idea of there being a defaults setting for this.

@AVelj There is, in fact, a defaults setting for this: https://macos-defaults.com/desktop/createdesktop.html ... no effect. But good call anyhow! :-) Oh, and I'm not on an external display.

@jackisquizzical Ah damn. Thought it would fix it for you :(

Here's solution:
    cd ~/Desktop
    chflags nohidden *    

(You could do less than *, obviously.)
I ran into it here:
https://kb.mit.edu/confluence/display/istcontrib/How+to+make+your+Library+folder+visible+in+the+Finder+in+OS+X+10.9+%28Mavericks%29+or+later
